# My Postgres query is not working properly

Tags: postgresql-9.3

```
select * 
from data_adultdata 
where sex = 'Male'
```

when I am not giving space before 'Male', its return nothing:

[image]

```
select * 
from data_adultdata 
where the sex= ' Male'
```

when I am giving space before ' Male' then it returns correct record.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble's not in Postgres but in the data, you can simple check it:

```
select length('Male') = length(title), length(' Male') = length(title) 
from data_adultdata 
limit 10;
```

Comment: @Palani P  have you tried the solution, is it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

When your trying to match strings, it's prefereable to use `Like` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data_adultdata 
WHERE sex LIKE '%Male'
```

but Bear Brown is right, the input data is seems to have an additional character of a space which is why you don't get 'Male'